# NetSuite Web API - How to return/populate customFieldList array for Sales Order from a joined search?

Tags: c#, netsuite, suitetalk

I am currently performing a SuiteTalk search via C# that joins multiple tables, one of which is for Sales Orders.  When performing a typical GET on a SalesOrder record, the property customFieldList gets populated with an array of transaction custom fields/etc. I am curious how to get the same when doing a search like:

```
SearchResult searchResult = Client.Service.search(new TransactionSearchAdvanced()
{
    criteria = new TransactionSearch()
    {
        basic = new TransactionSearchBasic()
        {
            type = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField()
            {
                @operator = SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf,
                operatorSpecified = true,
                searchValue = new String[] { "_salesOrder" },
            },
            lastModifiedDate = new SearchDateField()
            {
                @operator = SearchDateFieldOperator.after,
                operatorSpecified = true,
                searchValue = fromLastModifiedDateTime.ToUniversalTime(),
                searchValueSpecified = true
            }
        },
    },
    columns = new TransactionSearchRow()
    {
        basic = new TransactionSearchRowBasic()
        {
            internalId = new SearchColumnSelectField[] { new SearchColumnSelectField() },
            tranId = new SearchColumnStringField[] { new SearchColumnStringField() },
            tranDate = new SearchColumnDateField[] { new SearchColumnDateField() },
            dateCreated = new SearchColumnDateField[] { new SearchColumnDateField() },
            item = new SearchColumnSelectField[] { new SearchColumnSelectField() },
            quantity = new SearchColumnDoubleField[] { new SearchColumnDoubleField() },
            lastModifiedDate = new SearchColumnDateField[] { new SearchColumnDateField() },
            email = new SearchColumnStringField[] { new SearchColumnStringField() },
            //customFieldList = new SearchColumnCustomField[] { },
        },
        itemJoin = new ItemSearchRowBasic()
        {
            itemId = new SearchColumnStringField[] { new SearchColumnStringField() },
            type = new SearchColumnEnumSelectField[] { new SearchColumnEnumSelectField() },
        },
        customerJoin = new CustomerSearchRowBasic()
        {
            internalId = new SearchColumnSelectField[] { new SearchColumnSelectField() },
            billAddress = new SearchColumnStringField[] { new SearchColumnStringField() },
            companyName = new SearchColumnStringField[] { new SearchColumnStringField() },
            phone = new SearchColumnStringField[] { new SearchColumnStringField() },
            email = new SearchColumnStringField[] { new SearchColumnStringField() },
        },
        customSearchJoin = new CustomSearchRowBasic[] 
        {

        },
    }
});
```

The property I want populated is commented out within the TransactionSearchRowBasic object:
***//customFieldList = new SearchColumnCustomField[] { },***

Any ideas?  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The search operation doesn't return as much information as a GET operation does on the SuiteTalk Web Services.

For each record that is returned in your SearchResult, use the internalId or document number to GET that record. This should then include your custom fields.

```
NetSuiteService _service = new NetSuiteService();
ReadResponse res = _service.get(new RecordRef { internalId = internalID, type = RecordType.salesOrder, typeSpecified = true });
```

Comment: That is actually what I was trying to avoid (multiple calls).  This will actually be run on a timed process that could bring back thousands of records.  Making the initial call to then loop through and make individual subsequent calls (even batched) will kill performance.

That being said, if that is what has to be done, it is what has to be done.

Comment: I have this issue myself where I would prefer to make fewer API calls during some of my operations. In this case, I don't have any simpler solution at this point.

Comment: Appreciate the response.  I have a conversation going with NetSuite at this point.  I did some benchmarks performing the joined search (current without custom field list) and then adding in a batched getlist call to get the order information.  For 49 records, it jumps from 14 sec to 42.  Hopefully we can find a solution for it.  I will post if so.

Comment: I hope you manage to solve this. I would be interested to know how this should be done. Please do post when you find your solution.